# Intersection of pairs of sets (any possible combination)

Tags: r, intersection

I have more than theree sets, but here I wrote the following example.

```
S1<-c("Frizzy","Jack","Amy")
S2<-c("Alice","Samy","Anna","Jack")
S3<-c("Frizzy","Anna","Fred","Jack")
```

I would like to obtain the following result

```
length(intersect(S1,S2))+length(intersect(S1,S3))+length(intersect(S2,S3))
```

without write manually all the possible combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `combn` to get the pairwise `intersect` between the elements, get the `lengths` of the `list` elements and find the `sum`

```
sum(lengths(combn(list(S1, S2, S3), 2,
      FUN = function(x) Reduce(intersect, x), simplify = FALSE)))
#[1] 5
```

---

If there are many objects of the same pattern 'S' followed by some digits, use `mget` to get those all into a `list` instead of writing them manually

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^S\\d+$'))
sum(lengths(combn(lst1, 2, 
     FUN = function(x) Reduce(intersect, x), simplify = FALSE)))
#[1] 5
```

Comment: Thank you! What if they were the columns of different dataframe?

Comment: @Mark You can wrap them in a list as `list(df1$S1, df2$S2, df3$S3)` assuming they have different lengths

Comment: Similar: `L = list(S1, S2, S3); n = length(L); sum(combn(1:n, 2, FUN = function(i) length(intersect(L[[i[1]]], L[[i[2]]]))))`

Comment: @Mark Are those having the same number of dimensions.  I would get all the data.frames `ls()` i.e. `lst1 <- mget(ls()); lst2 <- do.call(`c`, lapply(lst1[sapply(lst1, is.data.frame)], unclass))` and then on `lst2`, apply the `combn` as in the second block of code